# Type 'byte' could not be resolved

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I've just installed the NDK onto Eclipse, but I'm having some trouble with something..

Here's the code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void deleteFile(const char *fileName) {
    remove(fileName);
}

void writeFile(const char *fileName, byte array) {

}
```

But something is going wrong.. I got this error:

```
jni/[projectName].cpp:9:38: error: 'byte' has not been declared
```

byte couldn't be resolved! which is a big problem because I absolutely need that type.. I have to use it to write data into a file!

I've followed a lot of tutorials, I also tried to import all of my MinGW libraries with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`byte` isn't a standard C or C++ type ... It may be a `typedef` in a non-standard header file. Where have you seen code with that type ? May be you would like to use `const unsigned char *` ?

I know that Visual Studio define BYTE type:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;   // 8-bit unsigned entity.
typedef BYTE *        PBYTE;  // Pointer to BYTE.
```

But this is not standard. And it is "BYTE", not "byte".

Comment: He's coming from a Java world where `byte` is a standard 8-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 2):

'byte' doesn't exist in standard C or C++, if all your code depends on , use 'jbyte' instead, it is defined in this header, and maps to an 8-bit unsigned integer type.

Alternatively, you could define 'byte' with a typedef as in:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

And ensure this is used/parsed by all your sources (e.g. put it in a shared header).

A slightly more correct way to do it is:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef uint8_t byte;
```

It will be equivalent on all supported Android platforms, but requires an additional include.

(Technically, 'char' can be more than 8 bits on some really odd platforms, but none of them are ever going to be targetted by Android).